# How to execute all function inside a loop before looping again?

Tags: c#, for-loop

please help me i wanted to set my pictureBox into visible for only 1 second then hide it again before going to the next loop. here's my code.

```
private void sampleTxt_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    words = "AB"
    char[] ch = words.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ch[i] == 'A')
        {
            a = true;
            Application.Idle += imageA;
        }
        else if (ch[i] == 'B')
        {
            b = true;

            Application.Idle += imageB;
        }
    }
}

private void imageA(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    TimeSpan ts;            
    if(a == true) 
    {
        letterA.Visible = true;
        stopWatchA.Start();
        ts = stopWatchA.Elapsed;
        if (ts.Seconds >= 1)
        {
            stopwatch();
            letterA.Visible = false;
            a = false;                   
        }
    }
}

private void imageB(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    TimeSpan ts;
    if (b == true)
    {
        letterB.Visible = true;
        stopWatchB.Start();
        ts = stopWatchB.Elapsed;
        if (ts.Seconds >= 0.5)
        {
            stopwatch();
            letterB.Visible = false;
            b = false;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem with my code is that it displays both images at the same time.
I want to display the letter "A" image for 1sec first before looping again to display the second image. Is that possible?

Comment: Where is the next loop?

Comment: Your 2 image methods don't loop, they just check the ts once

Comment: What is `stopwatch()`?

Comment: you loop through the letters, twice around the loop, once for each letter/image. To me the behaviour sounds like what would be expected.

Comment: stopwatch() will reset the timer.

Comment: If you want the picture to be displayed for X seconds, you should use a Timer and keep track in a variable of which image is displaying, then on the timer tick, change it to the other one.

Comment: I want to display the letter "A" image for 1sec first before looping again to display the second image.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop on letterB, also maybe change the timer from 0.5 to 1.0